# Can odoo companies share the same partner ? In which scenarios?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo, erp

I have seen the odoo code for the creation of a new company:

```python
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    if not vals.get('name', False) or vals.get('partner_id', False):
        self.cache_restart(cr)
        return super(res_company, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
    obj_partner = self.pool.get('res.partner')
    partner_id = obj_partner.create(cr, uid, {'name': vals['name'], 'is_company':True, 'image': vals.get('logo', False)}, context=context)
    vals.update({'partner_id': partner_id})
    self.cache_restart(cr)
    company_id = super(res_company, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
    obj_partner.write(cr, uid, [partner_id], {'company_id': company_id}, context=context)
    return company_id
```

The first three lines seems to allow the new company to be created using the specified partner..

This seems to intentionally omit the association of the given partner to the newly created company (the line before the last return).

Is this a bug or they want to allow a company to share the partner with another company ? In which scenarios would this be useful ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, in Odoo 8 or older, it's not possible to share a contact between companies. A lot of customers asked me for implementing that, because they wanted to introduce contacts who work in several companies (and even those contacts were the main contact of those companies).

In fact, you can check the behaviour of the official module `base_contact` to share contacts between companies. If you read the code of this module, you will realize that actually they are creating several contacts for each company, and then they hide them in order to make the user see only one of them.

Example: you create a contact named *Yucer* in the company *Odoo* (this contact will be created as `standalone` type). Then, you want to indicate that this partner also works for the company *StackExchange*. When you do this, another contact (with the same data of *Yucer*) is stored in the database, with the type `attached`. When you search for *Yucer*, you will only see the `standalone` one, but if you check *Odoo* and *StackExchange*, you will see *Yucer* in both of them. They also modified ORM methods of `res.partner` model like `unlink`, to remove all cloned contacts when you remove the main one.